# Change the banner background and foreground colors to make them more visible

Tags: feature-request, notification-bar

On meta, for instance, this would be much more visible on the Questions page.

[image: Reputation scoring has been revised and recalculated on all Stack Overflow family sites.]

Comment: A few hours ago I thought about proposing this, but then I guessed it would be declined because this questions will stop soon

Comment: Regardless -- important announcements should pop out from the interface -- check out the jQuery UI themes with respect to active/alert/highlight states.

Comment: is that a pun to "you should totally drop that and use jQuery"?

Comment: It can't hurt to add a <blink> tag too.